# Modal form show error when submitting and prevent it from closing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

This is my html code for my modal form.

```
<form  action="" class="cd-form" method="POST" id="signinform" onsubmit="return: false;">
    <p class="fieldset" id="warningPanel">
        <?php ShowAlertWarning(); ?>
    </p> 
    <p class="fieldset">
        <label class="image-replace cd-username" for="signin-username">Username</label>
        <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="signin-username" name="login_username" type="text" placeholder="Username" required>
        <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
    </p>
    <p class="fieldset">
        <label class="image-replace cd-password" for="signin-password">Password</label>
        <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="signin-password" name= "login_password" type="password"  placeholder="Password" required>
        <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
    </p>
    <div id="remember">
        <p class="fieldset">
            <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me" >
            <label for="remember-me">Remember me</label>
        </p>
    </div>
    <input class="full-width" type="submit" name="login" value="Login" id="signin_button">
</form>
```

And this is also my php code.

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){ 
    $username = stripslashes($_POST['login_username']);
    $password = stripslashes($_POST['login_password']);

    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);


    $sql = "SELECT user.userID, user.password, profile.firstname FROM user, profile  WHERE username = '$username' AND user.userID = profile.userID";
    $result = $con->query($sql);

    if($result->num_rows > 0){

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

            $chk_password = $row['password'];
            $chk_firstname = $row['firstname'];
            $userID = $row['userID'];
            $_SESSION['userID'] = $userID;
            if(password_verify($password, $chk_password)){
                $_SESSION['username_logged_in'] = true;

                if(empty($chk_firstname))
                    header('Location: profile.php');
                else
                    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
          $showWarning = true;
          session_destroy();
        }
}

function ShowAlertWarning(){

        global $showWarning;
        $newShowWarning = $showWarning;

        if($newShowWarning){
            echo '<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-danger form-feedback">';
            echo '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>';
            echo '<strong>Oh snap!</strong> Wrong username or password, please try again.';
            echo '</div>';          
        }
}
```

Is there anyway I can show the error inside my modal form without
closing it? I have this also `ShowAlertWarning()` function that
it will display in my modal form without refreshing my page.

Comment: else{
          $showWarning = true; ShowAlertWarning();
          session_destroy();
        }

Comment: You have to use [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for this. 1. Send the form to the server without refreshing. 2. Get the response and put it into your modal. If you need help with it, please nutify us.

Comment: I am completely a newbie when it comes to web development. Can you show me some tutorial on how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

take `type="submit"` off of the submit button. That is whats closing the form. Then instead add to the input `onclick="yourCustomFunctionHere()"` and write a function with JS that will check for fields to not be empty and only submit it if they are all full.